# Killing a process based on nice value (bash)

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am currently doing an exercise that requires me to write a script that kills the "sleep" process based on the nice value of it. So in one terminal, a sleep command of 100 (with the default niceness value of 0) would be terminated immediately when I run my script in another terminal. However, I'm having trouble writing the script for it. Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
nice="$(ps eo pid,user,nice,command | grep sleep)"

if nice <= 4
  then
  kill -9 sleep
fi
```

My question is: How do I get the nice value from a command into a simple variable that I can run through my if statement?

Also, I'm running into trouble running my scripts. When I have a sleep command run in one terminal, and try to input `sh kill_sleep.sh`, it insists that it can't open it. What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do it simply even without `awk`:

```
read pid nice < <(ps -C sleep ho pid,nice)
if (( $nice <= 4 ))
    then kill $pid
fi
```

- `-C` filters only `sleep` commands in `ps` output
- `h` in `ps -C sleep ho` suppresses output of names of columns (header)
- `read` assigns the according values to variables `pid` and `nice`
- `kill` might be with `-9` if you prefer
- `<(...)` construct is [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html), it allows to read from process output as if it was a file

If you want to reflect the possibility of several running `sleep` instances (and kill all which are not *nice*), you can read `ps` output in `while` loop:

```
while read pid nice; do
    if (($nice <= 4))
        then kill $pid;
    fi
done  < <(ps -C sleep ho pid,nice)
```

Comment: I like yor solution more than mine, maybe I would replace `<<<$(...)`  with `< <(...)` for better compatibility.

Comment: Thanks! I'll edit it. However, your point that there can be more `sleep` instances is valid and my solution doesn't reflect it. I leave this as our solutions can be easily combined.

Comment: I've added the `while` loop from @j.a. 's deleted solution. Thx!

Comment: Thank you for the response and explaining everything. One question though: How would I make this script run forever, as in, it continues to kill sleep commands that have nice values under 4 until I ^C it?

Comment: A simple way is to wrap the code with another (infinite) while loop like this: `while true; do <here you put the code>; sleep 1; done`. This executes the killing roughly once a second.

Answer (score 4):

The command below kills all sleep processes with niceness <= 4:

```
ps -o pid= -o nice= -C sleep | awk '$2<=4{system("kill " $1)}'
```

The option `-C sleep` tells `ps` to select only `sleep` commands.

The options `-o pid= -o nice=` specify that `ps` should output the process ID and the nice value while omitting the header.

In the awk command, `$2<=4` selects only those lines that have nice less than or equal to 4.  (Since `nice` is the second value on each line of `ps` output, awk refers to it as `$2`.)

For those selected lines, the awk command `system("kill " $1)` is run.  This runs the shell command `kill` on the pid.  (Since PID is the first value on each line of `ps` output, awk referes to it as `$1`.)

The `kill pid` command sends the process the default signal which is `TERM`. This signal allows the process to shut down properly.  `kill -9` should [almost always be avoided.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8916/when-should-i-not-kill-9-a-process)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` to match one column and return another column:

```
sleep=$(ps eo pid,nice,command | awk '$3 == "sleep" && $2 <= 4 {print $1}')
if [ "$sleep" ]
then kill $sleep
fi
```